# Where is "shell script" in Automator?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, automator

I am trying to add Sublime to right-click in Finder on Mountain Lion.

When I open Automator, I do not see any shell script as options.

Here is a video frame from the the tutorial:

[image]

and here is mine

[image]

How do I find "shell script" – do I need to activate something or install some utility?

Answer (score 0):

All default Automator actions are stored in `/System/Library/Automator`. Open Finder, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, and go to that folder.

[image]

If you don't see anything there, that'd be very weird to see because something must have deleted those actions. In that case, you can try checking an older backup of your machine if those `.action` files are there.

If you don't have a backup, you could reinstall your system, or I could upload these default actions somewhere for you to download and put back in their right place. They're about 129 MB in total.

Comment: Thanks. I have the actions in that folder. They do not show up in the automator - at least not when I open it with spotlight and click service

Comment: Can you see if it only fails for Services? Could you test it on another user account perhaps?

Comment: Nothing on folder action and I do not have any other user account.

Comment: So does it work for Workflows, Applications, Print Plugins, et cetera? You could simply create an account through your System Preferences and then delete it later. Please also check `Console.app` for possibly relevant logging messages. Try quitting Automator and deleting `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Automator.plist` and possibly `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Automator.LSSharedFileList.plist`.

Comment: Ok, I'll try...